# In R I need to merge 2 df with repeated events and find time between 2 dates

Tags: r, date, dplyr, merge, repeat

I have a dataframe, df1, with ID and a surgery date, sx_date.
Same patients can have multiple sx_dates.

In another dataframe, df2, I have ID and sample dates. Again, same patient can have multiple samles taken and thereby repeated dates for same ID. In this I have a third column describing name of sample.

I would like to describe, how many samples(from df2) were taken within 30 days from every sx_date from df1. I know last step is to calculate difference between the two dates.
But how to merge accordingly?

```r
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
date <- seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2010-10-09"), by = "6 days") 
df1 <- expand.grid(id = id, date = date)

id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
date <- seq(as.Date("2021-01-20"), as.Date("2021-11-09"), by = "4 days")
sample <- rep(c("hgb","crp","Na","K"),each=5)
df2 <- expand.grid(id = id, date = date, sample = sample)
df2 <- df2 %>% arrange(id)
```

Comment: Sample dataset:
**Create df1**
`id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
date <- seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2010-10-09"), by = "6 days")
df1 <- expand.grid(id = id, date = date)%>%view()`
**Create df2**
`id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
date <- seq(as.Date("2021-01-20"), as.Date("2021-11-09"), by = "4 days")
sample <- rep(c("hgb","crp","Na","K"),each=5) 
df2 <- expand.grid(id = id, date = date, sample = sample)
df2 <- df2 %>% arrange(id)
df2 %>% view()`


Have tried
   
`Merge(df1, df2, by=”id”, all.x=T), but here it only keeps first sample date with multiple sx_dates`

Comment: @akrun, its available now, right?